# BootStrap Header Fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please find the below Jsfiddle code -

http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/3/

In the above code, when we scroll, the table header gets fixed to the top of the page.

However i have a masterpage which consumes top as 50 px.

How can the above code be tweaked so that whenever the page is scrolled the header of the `table` should be fixed at `50px` and not `0px`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [API](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/options) you can use `offsetTop: 50` in your fixed header intitialization for the dataTables plugin:

```
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table, {
    alwaysCloneTop: true,
    offsetTop: 50
});
```

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/260/

Hope that helps!

Comment: can see 2 headers at start in the above jsfiddle. how to hide and make it visible true only during scroll ?

Comment: Okay understood. But in your question you say that there is a master page that takes up 50px. I assume this master page is taking up the 50px and therefore the table header should be hidden behind this master page content. Correct?

Comment: Take a look at this example if you want to remove the static header when the fixed header is shown. You will have to do some manual scroll checking http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/260/ . Take a look at the updated answer